# Invalid Google Credentials with Onesignal ionic2

Tags: cordova, push-notification, push, ionic2, onesignal

I'm trying to put push notifications in my chat app. The thing is that i keep getting this error on OneSignal : Invalid Google Credentials. I'm sure that i put the right server API key. On my ionic2 project, I've put this in my app.ts :

```
  class MyApp {
   @ViewChild(NavController) nav: NavController;

   rootPage: any = Accueil;

   pages: Array<{icon : string, title: string, component: any}>;

   constructor(public platform: Platform, private authService : AuthService, private alertController: AlertController) {
   this.initializeApp();
   }

   initializeApp() {
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));};

    window["plugins"].OneSignal.init("MTUxMDg0YjYtZmFiMS00ZTE2LTk3NmYtZWNjMjY3YTdkMDc5",
                                   {googleProjectNumber: "220513038393"},
                                   notificationOpenedCallback);                  
   // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your
   // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
});
}
```

Where do you think would be the error ?!

My other question is how to manage the notifications that are sent from my server ( NODE JS) so that the user can receive a push notification every time he receive a new message ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your OneSignal app id as the first parameter to init, not what you have there. It's in a UUID format and looks like `"b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba"`. You can find this value on the settings page for your OneSignal app.

Comment: I found it : 0fe7be35-7a59-4739-b97d-5bb618c45598 Still i cant see the push on the device